# Why do shells look different for different users?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, server

I have a server in which there are 2 users: root and bob while I am logged in as root, everything look normal. Files are colored according to type, I can press up and down to search for previous typed commands, and I can see the current folder name in the shell prompt.

Being logged in as user bob everything seems "weird", nothing is colored, pressing up and down give me weird characters in the command line like "^[[A^[[B" and I can only see the character "$" in the command line prompt.

Is there a way to fix the issue?

Comment: Change the users login shell to "/bin/bash" in /etc/passwd

Comment: That should have been the right answer! thanks!

Comment: Is it within the terminal itself that the arrow keys give you weird characters, or inside `vi`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible features could be causing this.

The first: your two users could be using different terminals (i.e. bash, busybox, etc.)

You can change this per user in the `/etc/passwd` file

The second comes down to preferences, typically stored in `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_rc` and `~/.bash_profile`. ("~" refers to the home directory for that user, also found in `/etc/passwd` file, typically "/home/USERNAME").